# Is there a persistency layer for list/queue containers?

Tags: c++, linux, containers, persistence

Is there some kind of persistency layer that can be used for a regularly-modified list/queue container that stores strings?

---

The data in the list is just strings, nothing fancy. It could be useful, though, to store a key or hash with each string for definite references, so I thought I'd wrap each string in a struct with an extra key field.

The persistency should be saved on each modification, more or less, as spontaneous power offs might happen.

---

I looked into Boost::Serialisation and it seems easy to use, but I guess I'd have to write the whole queue everytime it gets modified to close the file and be safe for power offs, as I see no journaling option there.

I saw SQLite, but it could be over the top as I don't need relations or any sophisticated queries.

And I don't want to reinvent the wheel by doing it manually in some files.

Is there anything available worth looking into?

I have few experience with C++ and an OS beneath, so I'm unaware of what's available and what's suitable. And couldn't find any better.

Comment: Note that queue is a little tricky because it only natively supports access to the front element (just as stack only natively allows access to the top element). It does provide access to the wrapped container but then you are no longer working with a pure queue.

Comment: I probably need deque funtionality anyway so I'm happy with any flexible list type :)

Answer (score 0):

Potentially simpler alternative to relational databases, when you don't need those relations, are "nosql" databases. A document oriented database might be a reasonable choice based on the description.

Comment: I had a look at many of these but unfortunately couldn't find hardly with up-to-date maturity, compatible license, in-process/embedded-ness and C/C++ API.
MongoDB: license; leveldb: probably too linear;
LiteSQL: Pros over SQLite unclear, maybe useful;
UnQLite: release a tad old, but looks good

Comment: @eeroika Not sure what you mean, I only have one process, the application, and one database, which should be in-process and w/o any db server.

Comment: @jfk Sorry, I was actually thinking of another question when commenting, so it must have been confusing. To improve my response: Consider that you don't necessarily have to have only one process.